# Nokogiri error on installation due to missing native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying to install Ruby on Rails based on [these instructions](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04). However, I am getting the following error upon running `gem install rails -v 4.2.4`:

```
Fetching: rack-1.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.6.4
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150909-22683-172bl7d.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/falak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/falak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I tried installing nokogiri using system libraries by running `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.2.1 -- --use-system-libraries`, but I got the following error:

```
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150909-23169-twqmu6.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:637:in `try_ldflags'
    from /home/falak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1780:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:338:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/falak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/falak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try installing the `libgmp-dev` library

```
apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

Using RVM to install rails in ruby 2.2.3 has been a major problem among other users as well. For now, you can still get rails 4.2.4 in ruby 2.2.2.
Try:

```
    rvm install 2.2.2
    rvm --default use 2.2.2
    gem install rails
```

this should still work. RVM for some reason does not install the right headers in 2.2.3 for you to build the gems.

Answer (score 2):

For **OS X** users: remember update the Xcode command line developer tools, this is the problem for the 99% OS X users. `xcode-select --install`

Comment: this is actually a part of solution for me in 2017. But I got this error instead now `While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.`

Comment: @rattanak, try adding 'sudo' in the front of your command. Then it will ask for your password

Comment: I tried. `sudo gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.`

Comment: Try sudo gem install nokogiri -n /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 2):

You can try this amazing solution for this

The solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Or, if that doesn't work, depending on your ruby version, run something like:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Should fix your problem.

Still not working? Try the following after installing ruby-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for nokogiri error:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says check in the `mkmf.log` file. There you'll find the missing header files.

In my case I was missing zlib.h. The error was:

> The #include file "zlib.h" is not found

So to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

To find required dev packages, one can use `apt-file`

```
$ apt-file search zlib.h
zlib1g-dev: /usr/include/zlib.h
```