# getting error on rails -v / rails new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

getting error on rails new myapp

```
/home/high-tech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 19 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/high-tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/home/high-tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /home/high-tech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /home/high-tech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /home/high-tech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: So you need railties' (>= 0) Try the solution in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212116/rails-could-not-find-railties

Comment: This both errors solved with the help of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492424/error-installing-rails-error-failed-to-builed-gem-native-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails' dependencies might not be correctly installed.

Try the following:

```
bundle show railties
```

If it fails:

```
gem install railties
```

to install the gem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: it is done for rails new but give me error on  bundle install.


/projects/myapp$ bundle install
/home/high-tech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 19 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: In the thread that PolarisUser mentioned, Arkaaito said that, for him, it was because he installed rails using sudo, give a try to `gem install rails` if you did too.

Comment: gem install rails  is failed.

Comment: Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 /home/high-tech/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151027-25878-xhfsdy.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.